# problem running system.net.webclient and process.start off a control event

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

The following code causes my vs 2008 wpf project to hang, I'm not sure why.  Both Part 1 and Part 2 work perfectly fine independently, but when I run them together on an control event (click a button for example) the program hangs. I've also tried shell execute for part 2 - same results. However, this code when run within the form loaded event works fine. Any insights would be truly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'Part 1
    Dim myWebClient As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim CurrentDataFileContents As String = myWebClient.DownloadString("http://www.xyz.com")
    myWebClient.Dispose()

    'Part 2
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.test.com")

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the hang problem.  The app blocks for a second or so when I click the button, until the default web browser opens up and shows the test.com website.  But after that, the app gains control.  This is what I would expect, more or less.  If your experience is different, you might want to single-step through the code, or try an HTTP debugger (e.g. Fiddler, http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2) to try and figure out whether the DownloadString() call completes successfully.

Comment: Thanks Oren, but unfortunately the problem continues for me. I've spent several hours on it so far. Results from the .downloadstring are as expected.  The hang happens with the process.start. I'll keep digging.

Comment: Thnaks for your help. I found the problem was also somehow tied to how I was populating a listview. I'm still not sure what was at the root of the problem, but I worked around it by finding another way to open a browser. It's less ideal because it seems to restrict me to internet explorerer, but by chance if someone else runs into this problem here's the code I used as a workaround to part 2 above 

Dim objIE As Object objIE = CreateObject
("InternetExplorer.Application") 
objIE.Navigate2("http://www.test.com")
objIE.Visible = True 
objIE = Nothing